# Por que o construtor não pode determinar o tipo genérico usado?

Tags: c#, .net, construtor, genéricos, inferência

Tentando:

```
public class Classe<T> {
    private readonly T campo;
    public Classe(T valor) => campo = valor;
}

var objeto = new Classe(42);
```

não funciona sem colocar o tipo no construtor e precisaria ser:

```
var objeto = new Classe<int>(42);
```

Já:

```
public class Factory {
   public static Classe<T> Create<T>(T valor) => new Classe<T>(valor);
}

var objeto = Factory.Create(42);
```

funciona sem o tipo genérico colocado, ele infere.

Qual o motivo do construtor não aceitar e o método estático aceitar?

Comment: Desculpa, o que não funciona? `var objeto = new Classe<int>(42);` isso não funciona é isso a sua pergunta?

Comment: há pelo que eu entendi é `var objeto = new Classe(42);` sem especificar o tipo de dado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não tem um motivo técnico, é perfeitamente factível, mas tem um motivo plausível para ser assim.

Não é simples fazer isso funcionar e tem outras formas de contornar, seja sendo explícito, seja fazendo uma *factory*. Então pra que gastar energia criando algo de pouco benefício? Já cogitaram fazer, e quem sabe um dia façam, mas até agora não viram tanto valor.

Na verdade, o construtor não é o problema, é que tem que fazer inferência da classe. Parece que é do construtor porque ele é usado para instanciar a classe, mas ela é que é genérica. Isto também precisa ser explícito:

```
public class Classe<T> {
    private readonly T campo;
    public Classe(T valor) => campo = valor;
    public static Classe<T1> Create<T1>(T1 valor) => new Classe<T1>(valor);
}

var o = Classe<int>.Create(42);
```

Mas foi explícito na classe, no método houve a inferência.

Então por que a fábrica não precisou? Porque a classe não é genérica.

É mais difícil achar qual sobrecarga do método que deve ser usado em algumas situações que pode haver ambiguidade, e até mesmo impedir quando não conseguir resolver, ou seja, em alguns casos não é possível ter a pequena vantagem. Pense que herança ou outras conversões implícitas podem gerar situações que não tem como saber o que chamar.

Mas o mais doido é isto:

```
var o = Classe<bool>.Create(42);
Write(o.campo.GetType());
```

O que acha que vai imprimir? `Int32` ou `Boolean`?

Precisa colocar o tipo na classe porque não tem inferência, então colocamos o `bool`, mas o método estático que cria a classe usa um `int`, então a classe que efetivamente será criada é de um inteiro e não de um booleano. Só não faço com o construtor para provar a mesma coisa porque o construtor não pode ser genérico. Só porque não permitiram, até porque fica feio.

Quanto mais aprendo menos gosto da ideia de construtores. Eles têm pouca utilidade e vários problemas. Métodos que constroem são tão ou mais úteis, e não tem os diversos problemas do [construtor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/36VNQm). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NJC9xN). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/GenericConstructor.cs).